# Помогите уменьшить Python код

Tags: python, рефакторинг

У меня есть код,который рисует графики.

```
df['Length'][df.Protocol == three.Protocol[0]].plot(ax = axes[0,0],title = three.Protocol[0],kind='hist',color='black')
df['Length'][df.Protocol == three.Protocol[1]].plot(ax = axes[0,1], title = three.Protocol[1],kind='hist', color='red')
df['Length'][df.Protocol == three.Protocol[2]].plot(ax = axes[0,2], title = three.Protocol[2],kind='hist', color='green')
```

У меня меняется всего два значения axes[0, n] n от 0 до 2
как с помощью цикла я мог бы изменять эти значения ,а не переписывать всю строку заново ,для каждого графика.

Comment: Даже не могу вообразить, что вызвало у вас сложности

Comment: Более идиоматично было бы: `df.loc[df['Protocol'] == three['Protocol'].iloc[0], 'Length']` вместо `df['Length'][df.Protocol == three.Protocol[0]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for n, color in enumerate(['black','red','green']):
    df['Length'][df.Protocol == three.Protocol[n]].plot(ax=axes[0, n], title=three.Protocol[n], kind='hist', color=color)
```

Answer (score 3):

как то так

```
colors = ['black', 'red', 'green']
for i in range(len(colors)):
    df['Length'][df.Protocol == three.Protocol[i]].plot(ax = axes[0,i], title = three.Protocol[i], kind='hist', color=colors[i])
```

код меньше не стал, но стал понятнее и появились плюшки в виде дальнейших удобств